# Does changing a singleton mailer in PHP (Laravel) affect other user requests?

Tags: php, laravel, singleton, swiftmailer, mailer

The Laravel 5.3 Mailer class is configured as a singleton according to this article https://laravel-news.com/allowing-users-to-send-email-with-their-own-smtp-settings-in-laravel

Let's assume a user in a requests sets Mail::setSwiftMailer to a different server in order to send mails via his mailserver/account.

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl');
$transport->setUsername('your_gmail_username');
$transport->setPassword('your_gmail_password');

$gmail = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Set the mailer as gmail
Mail::setSwiftMailer($gmail);
```

Does this affect other users? As far as I understood, the usual singleton characteristics do not apply in PHP http://blog.gordon-oheim.biz/2011-01-17-Why-Singletons-have-no-use-in-PHP/

> A Singleton created in one Request lives for exactly that request. A
>   Singleton created in another Request done at the same time will still
>   be a completely different instance. And it will occupy it’s own
>   memory. Those instances are not linked to each other. They are
>   completely isolated, because PHP is a Shared-Nothing architecture. You
>   do not have one single unique instance, but many similar instances in
>   parallel processes.

So does changing the mailserver for the singleton function change the mailserver for other users?

Does changing the Laravel config affect the other users? I assume at least here the answer is yes.

```
Config::set('mail', ['driver' => $mail->driver, 'host' => $mail->host, 'port' => $mail->port, ...]);
```

Comment: Seems you already have found your answer _...A Singleton created in one Request lives for exactly that request. A Singleton created...._

Comment: Ok, I just needed to know for sure as this would be a major problem. And I actually do not really understand the singleton concept in PHP then.

Comment: Here you can find a good example and usecase. https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simultaneous Requests to PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430883/simultaneous-requests-to-php-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the most simple Singleton implementation:

```
class Singleton {
    protected static $_instance = null;

    public static function newInstance()
    {
        if (null === self::$_instance)
        {
            self::$_instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    // disallowed
    protected function __clone() {}

    // disallowed
    protected function __construct() {}
}
```

It makes sure that *only one instance of this exists* within this one and single request.

So your Swift_SmtpTransport is a Singleton:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl');
```

This means that *every instance of Swift_SmtpTransport is the one you have just created* (for this request) (this does not mean that you can not change the properties - maybe the instance has getters and setters to be called after it has been created).

And now lets see what you have already found out:

> A Singleton created in one Request lives for exactly that request.

So it is ***per request*** and ***the request does also not affect other requests***. So **no, I do not think that other users are affected. Not even if you change the config as per single request**.

For more information also read: [Simultaneous Requests to PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430883/simultaneous-requests-to-php-script) - for each request a new independent process is forked which does not have anything to do with the others. The only thing is that they may block each other.

The documentation of Laravel says:

> Configuration values that are set at run-time are only set for the
>   current request, and will not be carried over to subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks for clarification on the config change. I was very unsure about that part.

Comment: The only exception of this would be if the config is shared across the multiple independent instances (e.g. if it is a file on the server which is read by fopen / fclose or e.g. a database). But the laravel dynamic config should live within its own interpreter process.

Comment: @Jo42 Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952224/laravel-configset-persist-through-requests - the config (as we found out) does not persist, but if you want to persist then use the database or environment variables).

Answer (score 0):

In conventional php every request is a different instance. nothing in inherited (variable wise) from an instance to another (from a request to another).

In the same instance, the mailer is a singleton during its lifespan

Comment: What exactly do you mean by conventional php? PHP in general? Or are there configurations that might behave differently?

Comment: You can launch a PHP process that doesn't die (keep on listening) via command. for example to serve a websocket port. it's not conventional but doable.